# Using shuffle method on list associated to another list shuffles them both?

Tags: python, list, random, shuffle

This is my code

```
import random

#Creating a list
li1=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

#Creating a copy of li1 to li2
li2=li1

random.shuffle(li1)

print (li2)
```

This will also shuffle `li2`, why? Is there a way of shuffling them independently?

How can I solve this issue? Thank you very much!

Comment: You've only got reference to a single list, use `li2 = li1[:]` instead

Comment: `li1` and `li2` are names.

Comment: Just because you write a comment saying that a list is being copied, this does not mean that the list is actually being copied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `li2 = li1`, you are not storing the copy of `li1` but the reference of `li1` list to `li2`.

In order to store the copy of `li1` to `li2`, do:

```
li2 = l1[:]

# OR, via functional approach 
# li2 = list(li1)
```

Or, you may use `copy.copy()` as:

```
import copy
li2 = copy.copy(li1)
```

Sample Example:

```
>>> import random
>>> li1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
>>> li2 = li1[:]  # creating copy

# shuffling li1
>>> random.shuffle(li1)

>>> li1    # Shuffled content li1
[2, 1, 8, 6, 5, 4, 3, 9, 7]
>>> li2    # li2 holds the original copy
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

>>> random.shuffle(li2)   # also shuffle li2
>>> li2
[1, 5, 8, 9, 7, 2, 4, 6, 3]
>>> li1
[2, 1, 8, 6, 5, 4, 3, 9, 7]
```

Comment: Or just `li2 = li1[:]` for the canonical sequence shallow copy approach (doesn't coerce to `list` if it was, say, `bytearray`, and tends to run faster in general, because syntax beats function calls in CPython speedwise).

Comment: @ShadowRanger: I agree on the part

Answer (score 0):

After `li1=li2`, both `li1` and `li2` points to the same list `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`. And [`random.shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html) shuffles the list *in place* and returns `None`. It can be easily seen from the following code snippet.

```
import random

li1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
li2 = random.shuffle(li1)

print(li1)  # [4, 9, 8, 6, 2, 5, 7, 1, 3]
print(li2)  # None
```

---

Use [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample) without replacement, as shown below.

```
import random

li1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
li2 = random.sample(li1, len(li1))

print(li1)  # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
print(li2)  # [4, 6, 2, 1, 7, 5, 8, 3, 9]
```